# Sending mail using mailx shell command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, email

I need some help with my ruby script. I have code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'date'

system 'curl https://xxx/yyy/zzz --cacert xxx.pem --cert xxx.pem --key xxx.pem >> hosts.txt'

document = JSON.load File.new("hosts.txt")
file = JSON.load File.new("admins.txt")
new_file = File.open("newfile.txt", "w")
personal_data = file['admins'].group_by { |e| e.delete('name') }

dupa = []
document['results'].map do |h|
  dupa << h.merge(personal_data[h['name']].first) if personal_data[h['name']]
end

#puts dupa
dupa.each do |a|
  if a["global_status_label"] != "OK"

       last_report = a["last_report"].to_s
       last_report = last_report[0..9]
       date_last_report = Date.parse last_report
       current_Date = Date.today
       difference_dates = (current_Date - date_last_report).to_i
                if difference_dates > 5
                        new_file.puts "#{a['name']}\t #{difference_dates}"
                end
    end
end
new_file.close
```

Everything works fine, but I need to send mail with some informations using only shell command mailx/mail. I know how to execute shell commands in Ruby and if I wanted to send only a mail it would not be a problem, but doing thay way I have to create new file with data `new_file.puts "#{a['name']}\t #{difference_dates}"` and then send this in email. Is there any possibility to put data like a['name'] or difference_dates or anything elese to the text of email? I think abou something like that:

```
system 'echo "Your server a['name'] is not responding since difference_dates, fix it!" |mailx -s "Warning" anything@anything.com'
```

is it possible and correct?